# Ruby on Rails 3: sort array based on data from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one array, which are IDs from one ActiveRecord table.
so I would like to sort that array based on last name which is associated with that ID...how can I do that?
To clarify:
array @students=[], inside are IDs and I would like to sort by Student.find(ID).last
Thank you.
Dorijan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without fully understanding the question, if you're given a list of id's, you can sort by last_name when you're doing the query:

```
Student.where("id IN (?)", @students).order(:last_name)
```

Of course, this assumes that @students is an array of ids and nothing else.

Responding to your comment, I'm not sure why you'd need to do that, but if your @student array is just a list of ids ignorant of the Student model and its attributes, and you would still like to order that array, you can do this:

```
@students = Student.where("id IN (?)", @students).order(:last_name).collect(&:id)
```

This will return an array of ids sorted by last name.  But again, I don't really know what you have going on behind the scenes, and I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: Hi...Thank you for quick reply, but I need to sort array @students=[], not order data from ActiveRecords. Example: in my array there are numbers [7,13, 15], and last name of 7 is Zorro and 13 is Anthony, 15 is Lovejoy, so, in final array should be [15,13,7]...

Comment: Obviously you would need your array to contain the data you wish to sort on if looking up said data in the database is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, you want to do the following:

- Take in a list of IDs of students as input
- Return a list of IDs ordered by the student's last name in the database.

You should be able to do the following:

```
Student.where(:id => @ids).order(:last_name).map(&:id)
```

Breaking this down:

- `where(:id => @ids)` only selects Students with an ID in the ID array.
- `order(:last_name)` sorts the results by last name.
- `map(&:id)` takes in an array of `Students` and returns just the ID column. Essentially, the method in brackets (which is a shortcut for calling `id` for each student) is called for each student found, and the return values are assembled into a new array (which will only contain the ids).

Some gotchas:

- If an ID doesn't exist in the database, it will be excluded from the results - if your result array is smaller than your input array, you may be trying to access a record that no longer exists.
- If the Students table has a lot of columns, you may want to consider calling `select(:id)` so that you don't pull every column of the Student records from the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Student.find( @students ).sort_by { |s| s.last_name }
```

Comment: This works well, but keep in mind it will do the ordering in memory, which may be inefficient if you have a large number of Student records to sort (particularly if the last_name column is indexed)